# The answer to the question "where do you go to school?"

Tags: grammar, american-english, questions, exam-questions

I had an English test last week and one of the questions was "Where do you go to school?" and the options were:

> a) by car
>
> b) by van
>
> c) to Rosario
>
> d) at Rosario
>
> e) on foot

Clearly a, b, and e are wrong but my doubt is between c and d. Which one would be correct?

Comment: I would answer just "Rosario", but (d) seems correct in this case. Think of turning the phrase into a whole sentence: "I go to school at Rosario" (not "I go to school to Rosario")

Comment: Is "Rosario" the name of your school?  My searching suggests it is the name of a town in Argentina, so "In Rosario" would seem to be the best answer.

Comment: @Esther But you might say "I go to Rosario". Your example does use "to" but in the form of "...to school at Rosario".

Comment: @WS2 yes, you could say "I go to Rosario." And if the question was "Where do you go?" then "To Rosario" would be the answer. But because of the "to school" clause there, you need the "at"

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that 'Rosario' is the name of the school, and that the answer is just those two words, then the correct answer would be "*to Rosario*".

It would be correct to say "*I go **to** Rosario*", which is tacitly implied by answering simply "*to Rosario*", because of the way the question is structured.

However, you could also express the same by saying "I am **at** Rosario school", as this is also an idiomatic way of expressing that you are *enrolled at* a school. It would also be correct to say "*I go to school at Rosario*".

You've obviously discerned that the other options are all modes of transport and so they would be possible answers to a question of *how* you go to school, not 'where'.

Comment: If you include the question in the answer, the only possible answer is **at**.  Where do you go to school?  *I go to school **at** Rosario.*

Comment: @EllieK Yes, I included that full response in my answer and stated that that was the correct rendition.

Comment: I don't see a scenario where the correct answer is *to Rosario*.  The correct but unavailable answer is *Rosario*.  Second best is *at Rosario*, based on the full answer of *I go to school at Rosario.*

Answer (score 1):

The correct but unavailable answer is *Rosario*.  Second best is *at Rosario*, based on the full answer of *I go to school at Rosario.*  However, including a preposition with the answer is unneeded and clumsy.

Best to solve this one with some verbal algebra.  Since the correct answer of *Rosario* is not offered we have to do some extrapolation to find which clumsy answer best fits the question.  To make the question clumsy like the answer lets add an unneeded preposition to it.

Should my clumsy question be -

> Where do you go to school to?

or should my clumsy question be -

> Where do you go to school at?

The correct clumsy question is, *Where do you go to school at,* and the correct clumsy answer is **at Rosario**.